# MouseMove not updating label.Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form on which there are three labels, whose values change when ever the mouse moves. Two work, the third doesn't. Here is my MouseMove code:

```
double latitude = Math.Round(Math.Acos(latRadius / maxRadius) * (180.0/Math.PI), 2);
label1.Text = x.ToString() + "," + y.ToString();
label2.Text = latRadius.ToString() + "," + maxRadius.ToString();
label3.Text = Convert.ToString(latitude);
```

The first two labels update properly, the third just keeps saying '90'. What's the problem?
Thanks

Comment: what result do you expect in label3.Text?

Comment: We can't see where you're setting variable values, and so can only assume that `latitude` is always 90, but you already knew that... this doesn't mean that the label doesn't update properly, but that there are issues with your numbers.

Comment: Have you checked, if there is the right value in latitude?

Comment: Is latRadius or maxRadius float or double?

Comment: I expect the result to change as the latitude is recalculated. This does not seem to be happening. latradius and maxradius, dependent variables, are changing, so I can't understand it.

Comment: I bet he has `latRadius` and `maxRadius` as integers

Comment: @Snowbear, yeah, they are integers :/

Comment: @NeoHaxxor, convert any of them to `double` or `float`. Integer division doesn't behave as you'd expect it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
double latitude = 
    Math.Acos(latRadius * 1d / maxRadius) * (180.0/Math.PI);
label3.Text = latitude.ToString("0.00");
```

**EDITED** to answer user comment:
your problem is you're using integers both for `latRadius` and `maxRadius` (I think); so when your app is evaluating `(latRadius / maxRadius)` it uses integer division and because of latRadius is less than maxRadius, it's always zero!
That's the reason you didn't see any update.
Now, using `(latRadius * 1d / maxRadius)` you force compiler to use real division (`*1d` means multiply for the double number 1) and the job is done.

**MORE**:
Don't use `Math.Round` on latitude if you are going to use it in other formulas.
Show it using two decimals with `latitude.ToString("0.00")`.